# Automatically run tests with each build in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest

When I run

```
xcodebuild -workspace ~/Documents/JudgecardXSwift/JudgecardXSwift.xcworkspace -scheme JudgecardXSwift -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6' clean test
```

from command line, I can successfully run all of my tests.

Now I want to add a run script phase to my Xcode project so it will always run my tests each time I run the app. However, when I added the run script phase with the above `xcodebuild` command, my build always hangs:

[image]

and as you can see, it must be hanging on the run script phase I added, because it has just finished the build phase before it titled `Run custom shell script 'Copy Pods Resources'`:

[image]

Is my method of adding a run script phase with the `xcodebuild` command the proper way to automatically run tests with every build? Why does it cause my build process to hang? Is it causing some kind of infinite loop with each `xcodebuild` command kicking off another through its run script phase?

Answer (score 0):

Bit late here, so thought I would add my personal experience, but xcodebuild will kick off another build for you, importantly xcodebuild via command line as you have may not run your Build Phases as expected. I have only experienced silent failing copy commands, with those I could view the command in log files, but it did not actually copy the file.

So it may hit an infinite loop, more likely though is it's running through that build, hitting xcodebuild command, and then building as normal without some Build Phases executing properly and thus without running your tests.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 9 this works. I've added a run script with:

```
echo "warning:  Started running myTests "

xcodebuild -sdk iphonesimulator -workspace myWorkspace.xcworkspace -scheme "myWorkspaceTests" test -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone X,OS=11.2' CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO
```

And if one of the tests fail, you're gonna get a build error.